# How to make my output appear in tkinter GUI instead of shell?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, output

I'm pretty new to coding so bear with me if my code looks like crap (which is probably does.) I just want my output to appear in the GUI I made instead of in the shell. How do I modify my code to make this happen?

```
import random
from tkinter import *

# Attributes
age = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
       "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39",
       "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58",
       "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77",
       "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96",
       "97", "98", "99", "100", ]
country = ["United States", "Brazil", "Mexico", "China", "Japan", "Canada", "France", "Germany"]
male_name = ["Joe", "Eden", "Diego", "Anthony", "Jarod", "Kique", "Austin", "Hunter"]
female_name = ["Haley", "Ariana", "Sarah", "Jackie", "Serena"]
gender_male = "Male"
gender_female = "Female"

# Random Generation
def print_start_life(event):
    Text(window, text=print(random.choice(age)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    Text(window, text=print(random.choice(country)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    Text(window, text=print(random.choice(male_name or female_name)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    if male_name:
        Text(window, text=print(gender_male), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    elif female_name:
        Text(window, text=print(gender_female), font=("Arial Bold", 16))


# GUI
window = Tk()
window.title("Random Life")
window.geometry('800x500')
lbl = Label(window, text="Do you want to play Random Life?", font=("Arial Bold", 25))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = Button(window, text="Yes")
btn.bind("<Button-1>", print_start_life)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove calling `print(...)` for all `text=print(...)`, e.g. `text=random.choice(age)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.  The problem you stated is due to calling `print(...)` in `text=print(...)`.  You don't need to call `print(...)`, just assign the argument of `print(...)` to `text` is enough.

Also you should not recreate `Text` widgets every time you click `Yes` button.  You should create `Label` widgets to display the random result once and then change their text in `print_start_life()` function.

Below is a modified version of your code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

# Attributes
age = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
       "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39",
       "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58",
       "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77",
       "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96",
       "97", "98", "99", "100", ]
country = ["United States", "Brazil", "Mexico", "China", "Japan", "Canada", "France", "Germany"]
male_name = ["Joe", "Eden", "Diego", "Anthony", "Jarod", "Kique", "Austin", "Hunter"]
female_name = ["Haley", "Ariana", "Sarah", "Jackie", "Serena"]
gender_male = "Male"
gender_female = "Female"

# Random Generation
def print_start_life(event=None):
    selected_age.config(text=random.choice(age))
    selected_country.config(text=random.choice(country))
    name = random.choice(male_name+female_name)
    selected_name.config(text=name)
    gender.config(text=gender_male if name in male_name else gender_female)

# GUI
window = Tk()
window.title("Random Life")
window.geometry('800x500')
lbl = Label(window, text="Do you want to play Random Life?", font=("Arial Bold", 25))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = Button(window, text="Yes", command=print_start_life)
#btn.bind("<Button-1>", print_start_life)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

frm = Frame(window)
font1 = ("Arial", 16)
font2 = ("Arial Bold", 16)
Label(frm, text='Age:', font=font1).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
selected_age = Label(frm, font=font2)
selected_age.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

Label(frm, text='Country:', font=font1).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
selected_country = Label(frm, font=font2)
selected_country.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

Label(frm, text='Name:', font=font1).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
selected_name = Label(frm, font=font2)
selected_name.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

Label(frm, text="Gender:", font=font1).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
gender = Label(frm, font=font2)
gender.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

frm.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used tkinter, but I am pretty sure this is the answer:

```
def print_start_life(event):
    Text(window, text=str(random.choice(age)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    Text(window, text=str(random.choice(country)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    Text(window, text=str(random.choice(male_name or female_name)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    if male_name:
        Text(window, text=str(gender_male), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    elif female_name:
        Text(window, text=str(gender_female), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
```

It looks to me like your text object is just calling the print function, rather than assigning a string to the text object.

Comment: If this answer was correct, I'd recommend upvoting it and marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use print to output to a Tkinter GUI.

The Text() you are also using is creating a text box with content in it that can be configured in several ways and also edited in the GUI, I think you are more wanting to just output your results. Either way, I coded up Text() to work as well as a alternate method using Label() to output a non-editable version. You will however have to find a way with Label to clear the previous output each time as you can see in outputs that they stack on each other.

*I only wrote in age and country to save a bit of time on my end*

```
import random
from tkinter import *

# Attributes
age = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
       "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39",
       "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58",
       "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77",
       "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96",
       "97", "98", "99", "100", ]
country = ["United States", "Brazil", "Mexico", "China", "Japan", "Canada", "France", "Germany"]
male_name = ["Joe", "Eden", "Diego", "Anthony", "Jarod", "Kique", "Austin", "Hunter"]
female_name = ["Haley", "Ariana", "Sarah", "Jackie", "Serena"]
gender_male = "Male"
gender_female = "Female"

# Random Generation
def print_start_life(event):
    age_display = Text(window, font=("Arial Bold", 16), width = 2, height = 1)
    age_display.insert(INSERT, str(random.choice(age)))
    age_display.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

    country_display = Label(window, text=str(random.choice(country)), font=("Arial Bold", 16))
    country_display.grid(column = 0, row = 2)



# GUI
window = Tk()
window.title("Random Life")
window.geometry('800x500')
lbl = Label(window, text="Do you want to play Random Life?", font=("Arial Bold", 25))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = Button(window, text="Yes")
btn.bind("<Button-1>", print_start_life)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

> [How to format your Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
>
> [How to use Text() in depth](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm)
>
> [How to use Label() in depth](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm)